# copy file from a remote PC by means of Powershell using UNC Path

Tags: file-transfer, powershell-2.0, unc

I need a way to copy file to local disk from a remote PC using **Powershell v2.0**, trying with admin rights of that remote PC. By means of below cmdlet we can copy a file:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\somefile.txt -Destination c:\someotherfile.txt
```

But my question is how to specify my local PC path as Destination path or the remote PC path as the source path in the above cmdlet? How to specify **UNC Path** for source or destination paths in above cmdlet?

Comment: You can use something like this `Copy-Item -Path 'C:\somefile.txt ' -Destination '\\targetserver\someotherfile.txt$'`.

Comment: Do you have to use the above cmdlet?? 

Robocopy could be a good answer for what you're attempting?